# SQL Select statement separate values into two columns

Tags: sql

I have string value in the column `Username`. 
Sample usernames:

```
USERNAME
--------
foobar123
john
smith23
steve
peter
king213
```

The user names with numbers at the end means that these users are no longer active. I want to separate these usernames into two columns `Active` and `Not_Active` in one Select Statement since i'll be using these for reports purposes.

Result should be:

```
Active    Not_Active
john      foobar123
steve     smith23
peter     king213
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    Username,
    (
        CASE Username
            WHEN '%[0-9]%' THEN 'Not'
            ELSE                'Active'
        END
    )
FROM
    Users;
```

I tried Case but I don't know how to get the username value.

Comment: You can't do this in a simple query because in your output data there is no relation between different column values in the same row - so I don't think you understand the nature of relational algebra and database query design.

Comment: You should determine your expected output first and edit your question according to it. With normal logic, you should want output with two columns: `usename` and `status(active, not_active)`. Your current expected output is weird. It could be archive using FULL OUTER JOIN using row number after we get 2 result set of all active and not_active user, but not good for normal sense

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Seems like you want some product specific functionality here.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment reply to your original posting, you don't want the data in the *same* output result-set; instead you will want two result sets (i.e. two tables), each with the different criteria.

Note that you cannot use `LIKE` string matching (`%`) with the `WHEN` statement in SQL. You have to use it in a `CASE WHEN` statement (one without a "switch" expression)

```
-- Result set one: Active users
SELECT
    UserName
FROM
    Users
WHERE
    UserName NOT LIKE '%[0-9]';

-- Result set two: Inactive users 
SELECT
    UserName
FROM
    Users
WHERE
    UserName LIKE '%[0-9]';
```

If you really want, you can combine these two queries into a single result-set with the data in different columns. This would be done by adding a `ROW_NUMBER()` column to each intermediate table, then doing a `FULL OUTER JOIN` on `ROW_NUMBER()`, however the output result would be meaningless and painful to iterate over in any consuming client code.

Another option might be a single result-set, with a computed `IsActive` column:

```
SELECT
    UserName,
    ( CASE WHEN UserName NOT LIKE '%[0-9]' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS IsActive
FROM
    Users
```

...which would be considerably easier to process in any consuming code.

Answer (score 0):

this format of saving data is quite useful in this one column holds username and other holds status of the user

`select username,
case username
when '%[0-9]% then inactive
else active
end as user_status
from table_1`

```
username   user_status
john       active
john123    inactive
```